# How do I find the libraries this program needs for its environment variable?

Tags: centos, environment-variables, libraries

I am trying to set up the program [NASAView](https://pds.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/subscription_service/software_detail.cfm?ResultsSelBox=nasaview), for viewing PDS files. The instructions say

> **Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH Environment Variable**
>
> The LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is used to locate the
>   NASAView-dependent libraries such as XVT and Motif. The following
>   command demonstrates how to set this variable, by appending to its
>   current setting.
>
> This example appends the locations of the NASAView-dependent libraries
>   found in the nasaview directory as well as the Motif libraries:
>
> [node:~] setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/openmotif-2.3.4/lib:$HOME/nasaview
>
> [node:~] echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> Once the UIDPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables have been set, the tool can be executed as demonstrated in the
>   following example:
>
> [node: /home/user/nasaview] ./nasaview

I haven't had any success trying to follow these instructions. It was built for CentOS, which I have installed on a virtual machine in order to use it, but I'm not used to it at all (I have an Ubuntu machine I'm a little more used to). In an earlier step I discovered the `setenv` command isn't recognized, and got advice to use `export` instead, which worked. Based on that, I believe what I need to use is

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:path/to/motif/library`

but I can't find that library. So I'm guessing what I need is to locate the motif library installed in my version of CentOS, and check what version it is. With that, then I complete the command with `/lib:$HOME/nasaview`?

Comment: What is output of `ldd ./nasaview`? Does CentOS ship Openmotif libraries? Did you tried to install Openmotif via package manager or by other means (finding RPM of it)?

Comment: @siblynx i took it from the brief instructions that Openmotif came as part of CentOS. I really don't know Linux but to use this program i had to go through this set up, i don't use the terminal usually. I'll look for the packages for CentOS, as cas also says below.

Answer (score 5):

Both xVT and openmotif are packaged for Centos.  Just install the packages and don't worry about setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

When you read instructions like this, you always have to stop and consider whether what it's telling you to do is actually necessary on your system.  Always check to see if a library or program is already packaged for your distro and use the packaged version if it exists rather than risk breaking your system by manually installing stuff you don't need to.